# websocket stop responding after handshake

Tags: websocket

I am building a websocket client (vb.net) with a simple socket.
I'm doing it to have better understanding of it before starting it on embedded project (cc3220).

It seems like i passed the handshake just fine, and after receiving one text frame the data stop to be received.

the websocket server is .net core Azure project works as echo. works great with simple websocket client chrome extension with multiple connections.

here is the log from my VB.NET app, maybe please someone can spot the problem:

```
--- Sending via socket-- 
GET http://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/xxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: WebSocket
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: gnuE6HbBVfsHzYVNLdxxbQ==


--- New pack received--- 
total bytes:206
72,84,84,80,47,49,46,49,32,49,48,49,32,83,119,105,116,99,104,105,110,103,32,80,114,111,116,111,99,111,108,115,13,10,85,112,103,114,97,100,101,58,32,119,101,98,115,111,99,107,101,116,13,10,83,101,114,118,101,114,58,32,75,101,115,116,114,101,108,13,10,83,101,99,45,87,101,98,83,111,99,107,101,116,45,65,99,99,101,112,116,58,32,84,101,70,54,79,103,112,48,109,79,106,118,102,105,99,70,82,116,90,48,107,105,52,114,83,49,103,61,13,10,88,45,80,111,119,101,114,101,100,45,66,121,58,32,65,83,80,46,78,69,84,13,10,67,111,110,110,101,99,116,105,111,110,58,32,85,112,103,114,97,100,101,13,10,68,97,116,101,58,32,84,117,101,44,32,49,48,32,65,112,114,32,50,48,49,56,32,50,48,58,51,56,58,53,54,32,71,77,84,13,10,13,10,0,
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Server: Kestrel
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: TeF6Ogp0mOjvficFRtZ0ki4rS1g=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Connection: Upgrade
Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2018 20:38:56 GMT


--- New pack receive--- 
total bytes:42
129,24,119,101,108,99,111,109,101,32,104,111,119,32,100,111,32,121,111,117,32,100,111,63,13,10,129,14,110,101,119,32,99,111,110,110,101,99,116,105,111,110,32,
welcome how do you do?
new connection 
Length: 24 op_code: 1(string data)

-- sending data (string 123) via socket, here there is no respond, the server should echo this ----
Sending string: 123
Sending bytes: 129,3,49,50,51,
Sending string: 123
Sending bytes: 129,3,49,50,51,


--- even when sending data via another websocket client app, the data is not received here, but it does to the third websocket client app ---
```

VbCode:

```
Public Class SocketObject
    Public socket As Socket = Nothing
    Public Const BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = 1024
    Public buffer(BUFFER_SIZE) As Byte
End Class 'StateObject

Dim sock As New SocketObject()

Private Sub printbytes(ByVal bytes() As Byte, ByVal size As Int16)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim a As String = vbCrLf + "--- New pack receive--- " + vbCrLf + "total bytes:" + size.ToString() + vbCrLf
    Dim b As String = ""
    For i = 0 To size
        a += bytes(i).ToString() + ","
        b += Chr(bytes(i))
    Next

    Dim c As String = ""

    If (bytes(0) >= &H0) And (bytes(0) <= &H7F) Then
        c = "(0x00 to 0x7F) --> Data... --> 0xFF "
    Else
        c = "(0x80 to 0xFF) --> Length --> Data..."
        c += " Length: " + bytes(1).ToString()

        Dim op_code As Byte = bytes(0) And &HF
        c += " op_code: " + op_code.ToString()

        Select Case op_code
            Case 9
                c += "(ping) response - Pong"
                Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
                Dim request As String = "  Pong"
                Dim bytesSent As [Byte]() = ascii.GetBytes(request)

                bytesSent(0) = &H8A
                bytesSent(1) = 4

                ' Send request to the server.
                sock.socket.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0)
            Case 10
                c += "(pong)"
            Case 1
                c += "(string data)"
            Case 2
                c += "(binary data)"
            Case 8
                c += "(connection close) - response and close"

                Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
                Dim request As String = " "
                Dim bytesSent As [Byte]() = ascii.GetBytes(request)

                bytesSent(0) = &H8

                ' Send request to the server.
                sock.socket.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0)
            Case Else
                c += "(unknown!!)"
        End Select
    End If

    Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, New Delegate_LableAddText(AddressOf LableAddText), a + vbCrLf + b + vbCrLf + c + vbCrLf + vbCrLf)
End Sub


Public Sub Read_Callback(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim so As SocketObject = CType(ar.AsyncState, SocketObject)
    Dim s As Socket = so.socket
    Try
        Dim read As Integer = s.EndReceive(ar)

        If read > 0 Then
            Dim frameCount = 2
            Dim bytes As Byte() = so.buffer

            printbytes(bytes, read)
        End If

        If (s.Connected = True) Then
            s.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, SocketObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Read_Callback), so)
        Else
            Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, New Delegate_LableAddText(AddressOf LableAddText), "-close-")
        End If
    Catch

    End Try
End Sub


Public Delegate Sub Delegate_LableAddText(ByVal str As String)
''' <summary>
''' Check the received data and see if there is command from the device to check
''' </summary>
''' <param name="str"></param>
Public Sub LableAddText(ByVal str As String)
    LblSock.Text += str
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    sock.socket.Close()
End Sub

Private Function random_sc_key() As String
    Dim s As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    Dim r As New Random
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i As Integer = 0 To "gnuE6HbBVfsHzYVNLdxxbQ==".Length
        Dim idx As Integer = r.Next(0, 35)
        sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1))
    Next
    Dim a As String = sb.ToString()
    Return "gnuE6HbBVfsHzYVNLdxxbQ=="
End Function

Private Sub BtnConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    LblSock.Text = ""
    'Set up variables and String to write to the server.
    Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    Dim request As String = "GET http://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/xxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1" + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Lf + "Host: xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net" + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Lf + "Connection: Upgrade" + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Lf + "Upgrade: WebSocket" + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Lf + "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Lf + "Sec-WebSocket-Key: " + random_sc_key() + vbCrLf + vbCrLf
    Dim bytesSent As [Byte]() = ascii.GetBytes(request)
    Dim bytesReceived(255) As [Byte]

    Dim hostEntry As IPHostEntry = Nothing

    ' Get host related information.
    hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net")

    Dim address As IPAddress

    For Each address In hostEntry.AddressList
        Dim endPoint As New IPEndPoint(address, 80)
        Dim tempSocket As New Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
        tempSocket.Connect(endPoint)
        If tempSocket.Connected Then
            sock.socket = tempSocket
            Exit For
        End If
    Next address

    If sock.socket Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Connection failed")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    LblSock.Text += "Sending: " + request

    ' Send request to the server.
    sock.socket.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0)

    LblSock.Text += "BeginReceive" + vbCrLf

    sock.socket.BeginReceive(sock.buffer, 0, SocketObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Read_Callback), sock)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSendString1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If (sock.socket.Connected = False) Then
        LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "connection closed" + vbCrLf
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim request As String = txtsock.Text
    request = "11" & request

    Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    Dim bytesSent As Byte() = ascii.GetBytes(request)

    bytesSent(0) = &H81
    bytesSent(1) = txtsock.Text.Length

    LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "Sending string: " + txtsock.Text
    LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "Sending bytes: "

    Dim i As Int16
    For i = 0 To bytesSent.Length - 1
        LblSock.Text += bytesSent(i).ToString() + ","
    Next

    sock.socket.Send(bytesSent)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnCloseSock_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If (sock.socket.Connected = False) Then
        LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "connection closed" + vbCrLf
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim request As String = txtsock.Text
    request = "1" & request & "1"

    Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    Dim bytesSent As Byte() = ascii.GetBytes(request)

    bytesSent(0) = 0
    'bytesSent(1) = txtsock.Text.Length
    bytesSent(bytesSent.Length - 1) = &HFF

    sock.socket.Send(bytesSent)
End Sub
```

Comment: Without code, it's very hard to help you... on a hunch I'd say that the client isn't encoding the WebSocket data correctly. Are you sure you're encoding the data according to the WebSocket protocol on the client? Is your client properly masking the data? Are you attaching the mask at the head of the encoded data (after the packet's header and before the data)?

Comment: Code attached, strings are UTF-8 encoded and i also added the bytes sent to and from the server and it looks similar to the protocol. but i still miss something.

Comment: This line: `bytesSent(1) = txtsock.Text.Length` is only valid for `txtsock.Text.Length < 127`. It also seems that the client isn't masking the message (clients MUST mask, servers must NOT mask, there's an encoding difference)... than again, I'm not any good with VB.NET. Consider adding the language's tag to your question, maybe you'll get more input.

Comment: About the framing (<127), i have another function that sends first byte 0 then the payload and last byte is 0xFF.
sending this frame result the same (server stop respond).

What do you mean MASK?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Myst that point me to the MASK issue.
here is the fixed code to preform simple text transmit to the server from the client:

```
Private Sub BtnSendString1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If (sock.socket.Connected = False) Then
        LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "connection closed" + vbCrLf
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim rand As Random = New Random()
    Dim masking_key(4) As Byte
    Dim i As Integer


    masking_key(0) = Convert.ToByte(rand.Next(0, 250))
    masking_key(1) = Convert.ToByte(rand.Next(0, 250))
    masking_key(2) = Convert.ToByte(rand.Next(0, 250))
    masking_key(3) = Convert.ToByte(rand.Next(0, 250))

    Dim request As String = txtsock.Text
    If (txtsock.Text.Length <= 125) Then
        request = "112222" & request

        Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        Dim bytesSent As Byte() = ascii.GetBytes(request)

        bytesSent(0) = &H80 Or 1
        bytesSent(1) = txtsock.Text.Length Or &H80
        bytesSent(2) = masking_key(0)
        bytesSent(3) = masking_key(1)
        bytesSent(4) = masking_key(2)
        bytesSent(5) = masking_key(3)


        Dim s As Integer = 0
        For i = 6 To bytesSent.Length - 1
            bytesSent(i) = bytesSent(i) Xor masking_key(s)

            s += 1
            If s = 4 Then s = 0
        Next

        LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "Sending string: " + txtsock.Text
        LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "Sending bytes: "

        For i = 0 To bytesSent.Length - 1
            LblSock.Text += bytesSent(i).ToString() + ","
        Next

        sock.socket.Send(bytesSent)
    ElseIf (txtsock.Text.Length <= 65535) Then
        request = "11111111" & request

        Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        Dim bytesSent As Byte() = ascii.GetBytes(request)

        bytesSent(0) = &H80 Or 1
        bytesSent(1) = 126 Or &H80
        bytesSent(2) = BitConverter.GetBytes(txtsock.Text.Length)(1)
        bytesSent(3) = BitConverter.GetBytes(txtsock.Text.Length)(0)
        bytesSent(4) = masking_key(0)
        bytesSent(5) = masking_key(1)
        bytesSent(6) = masking_key(2)
        bytesSent(7) = masking_key(3)

        Dim s As Integer = 0
        For i = 8 To bytesSent.Length - 1
            bytesSent(i) = bytesSent(i) Xor masking_key(s)

            s += 1
            If s = 4 Then s = 0
        Next

        LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "Sending string: " + txtsock.Text
        LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "Sending bytes: "

        For i = 0 To bytesSent.Length - 1
            LblSock.Text += bytesSent(i).ToString() + ","
        Next

        sock.socket.Send(bytesSent)
    Else
        request = "1111111112222" & request

        Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        Dim bytesSent As Byte() = ascii.GetBytes(request)

        bytesSent(0) = &H80 Or 1
        bytesSent(1) = 126 Or &H80
        bytesSent(2) = BitConverter.GetBytes(txtsock.Text.Length)(0)
        bytesSent(3) = BitConverter.GetBytes(txtsock.Text.Length)(1)
        bytesSent(4) = BitConverter.GetBytes(txtsock.Text.Length)(2)
        bytesSent(5) = BitConverter.GetBytes(txtsock.Text.Length)(3)
        bytesSent(6) = BitConverter.GetBytes(txtsock.Text.Length)(4)
        bytesSent(7) = BitConverter.GetBytes(txtsock.Text.Length)(5)
        bytesSent(8) = BitConverter.GetBytes(txtsock.Text.Length)(6)
        bytesSent(9) = BitConverter.GetBytes(txtsock.Text.Length)(7)
        bytesSent(10) = masking_key(0)
        bytesSent(11) = masking_key(1)
        bytesSent(12) = masking_key(2)
        bytesSent(13) = masking_key(3)

        Dim s As Integer = 0
        For i = 13 To bytesSent.Length - 1
            bytesSent(i) = bytesSent(i) Xor masking_key(s)

            s += 1
            If s = 4 Then s = 0
        Next

        LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "Sending string: " + txtsock.Text
        LblSock.Text += vbCrLf + "Sending bytes: "

        For i = 0 To bytesSent.Length - 1
            LblSock.Text += bytesSent(i).ToString() + ","
        Next

        sock.socket.Send(bytesSent)
    End If
    LblSock.ScrollToEnd()
End Sub
```